# How to update global variable through a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I've been trying to create a chat app with multiple rooms using MongoDB, Redis, NodeJS and socket.io. I need to query a Redis list called `roomDocumentState` and return the value into a variable. This variable has to be in the global scope and needs to be modified.

The code I've tried to use only modifies the local variable in the function. I've read that its something called "closure". Can someone show me how to implement it properly?

Here is the code for pulling data out of Redis and modifying the variable `count_1`:

```
function checkRoomDocumentState() {
  var count_1 = 0;

  store.llen(roomDocumentState, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        if (res > count_1) {
            count_1 = res;
            return count_1;
        }
    }
  });
}
```

So this function is called in the following way, here's a code snippet:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', client => {
  createWhiteboardRooms();
  sub.subscribe(roomDocumentState);
  store.lpush(roomDocumentState, event1);

  //added this to check if there's any value at all
  checkRoomDocumentState();
  console.log(checkRoomDocumentState()); 

  sub.on("message", (channel, message) => {
      console.log(message);
      client.send(message);
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you want to use `count_1`?

Comment: Basically, I have this function that checks if the value in a redis list has changed. This value will be gotten using 'llen' and then put in count_1. And the second function checks this variable and does some other stuff

Comment: I'm asking not about that how this variable is _initialized_, but how it will be _used_. Where do you call `checkRoomDocumentState`? If you want to use this variable immediately after the call, it will undefined, because `checkRoomDocumentState` is asynchronous function.

Comment: edited post to show this

Comment: Hey, [my first SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269409/extract-data-from-anonymous-function-scope) was about the same thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable that you want to make global is `count_1`, then you have to remove the `var` keyword in front of it.

But, as explained in the comment below, it is better to use callback to pass values:

```
function doSomethingAsync(resultIsAvailable) {
  redis.doSomethingElseAsync((err,res) => {
    result = 'redis told me ' + res;
    resultIsAvailable(result);
  });
}

doSomethingAsync((result) => {
  console.log('my function has been told by redis that ' + result);
});
```

Comment: If I do, then I see an "undefined variable" error in my IDE... Sorry, I'm a little confused and I've been messing with this for a while.

Comment: You should not use a global variable for your use case. It is cleaner and easier to pass your result via a callback: 1) change the signature of your function to checkRoomDocumentState(resultAvailable), 2) in the function, where you have computed count_1, call resultAvailable(count_1). In the code that calls checkRoomDocumentState, provide your callback function.

Comment: Could you please show my how to do that? I'm super confused about this right now. I just have no idea how to implement that.